# How to make a custom Image resizable() with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view

```
struct CustomImageView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("someImage")
    }
}
```

when i reference this view outside, i cannot make the image resizable.
I know i can pass parameters, but i was looking for a neater way to do this through modifiers?

```
VStack {
   CustomImageView()
      .resizable()    // This does not work
}
```

resizable seems to only work with the image directly.
Does anyone know how to make the CustomImageView resizable?

**Update:** I understand i can use a parameter, but is there anyway to do it using modifiers? Resizable was only one property, but there are other properties. And listing them all as indvidual variables will be too much

**Implemented Answer based on @matteo-pacini**
It uses AlamofireImage to load a remote image in ImageView.

```
struct RemoteImage : View {
    var url: URLConvertible
    @ObjectBinding var imageLoader = AlamofireImageLoader()

    private (set) var _resizable: (capInsets: EdgeInsets, resizingMode: Image.ResizingMode) = (EdgeInsets(), .stretch)

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: imageLoader.image)
            .resizable(capInsets: _resizable.capInsets, resizingMode: _resizable.resizingMode)
            .onAppear() {
                self.imageLoader.loadImage(url: self.url)
            }
    }

    func resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets = EdgeInsets(), resizingMode: Image.ResizingMode = .stretch) -> RemoteImage {
        return RemoteImage(url: url, _resizable: (capInsets, resizingMode))
    }
}

class AlamofireImageLoader: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var image = UIImage() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.didChange.send(Void())
            }
        }
    }

    convenience init(url: URLConvertible) {
        self.init()
        loadImage(url: url)
    }

    func loadImage(url: URLConvertible) {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
                self.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```swift
struct CustomImageView : View {

    private var isResizable = false

    var body: some View {
        let image = Image("someImage")
        return isResizable ? image.resizable() : image
    }

    func resizable() -> CustomImageView {
        return CustomImageView(isResizable: true)
    }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomImageView()
                .resizable()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand i can use a parameter, but is there anyway to do it using modifiers? Resizable was only one property, but there are other properties. And listing them all as indvidual variables will be too much

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com updated to use modifier - I think it's what `Image` does ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269730-resizable)).

Comment: @FlowUI.SimpleUITesting.com see my answer there is a solution :)

Comment: In my finding it looks like this is the closest we can reach when trying to create a custom component which on higher level feels and acts like native. To see a better example have a look at the `WebImage` from `SDWebImageSwiftUI` - https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI/blob/master/SDWebImageSwiftUI/Classes/WebImage.swift

Answer (score 2):

Like @FlowUI.SimpleUITesting.com mentioned the other answers suppose that you will edit only one property modifier. What if you would add others?

Simply in your CustomImageView add :

```
private let modifiers: (Image) -> Image

init(modifiers: @escaping (Image) -> Image = { $0 }) {
    self.modifiers = modifiers
}

var body: some View {
    modifiers(Image("someImage"))
}
```

Then simply use this way :

```
CustomImageView(modifiers : {$0.resizable().whateverModiferThatReturnImage().anotherOne()})
  .frame(width: 200)
  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
  .asUsualModifiersThatReturnViews()
```

Comment: This is a better answer, of course it would be nicer to have all the modifiers together, but it is the closest solution I found

Comment: Yeah, but many modifiers don't return an Image and then we're in trouble(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling .resizable() on CustomeImageView, which is of type View.

You need to call .resizable() on an Image type.

Your Image is nested in body, that's within CustomImageView.

```
struct CustomImageView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("someImage")
            .resizable()
    }
}

CustomImageView()
```

The reason this works is, it calls .resizable on Image(), instead of a View, like before. Hope this helps!

References:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view

Comment: sorry, but i think i was not clear. I know resizable work on the image, and not on the imageView. I am trying to create a reusable custom imageView. But the problem is that when that view is returned to the caller, it loses the `resizable` trait because the image is wrapped in a view. In order to make the customImageView felixible enough to be used by other classes, i need that resizable trait to be available. Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
struct CustomImageView: View {

    @State var isResizeable: Bool = false
    @State var capInsets: EdgeInsets = EdgeInsets()
    @State var resizingMode: Image.ResizingMode = .stretch

    var body : some View {

        ZStack {
            if isResizeable {
                Image("placeholder")
                    .resizable(capInsets: self.capInsets, resizingMode: self.resizingMode)
            }
            else {
                Image("placeholder")
            }
        }
    }

    func resizeable(capInsets: EdgeInsets = EdgeInsets(), resizingMode: Image.ResizingMode = .stretch) -> CustomImageView {
        return CustomImageView(isResizeable: true, capInsets: capInsets, resizingMode: resizingMode)
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {
        CustomImageView(isResizeable: true)
    }
}
```